# how to set "result to text" with a tsql statement in sp?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

is there any way to set "result to text" within of SP while this execute a process? a tsql stament?

Thanks.

Comment: I agree that this is not the job of SQL, but it would be nice if Microsoft would add some nice features like this to SSMS.

Answer (score 6):

No, how the results are displayed (if at all) is the job of the client application.

Answer (score 3):

`"result to text"`  is for client application

e.g. in SSMS when you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, you tell the client application (SSMS) to show / render the results of the query in TEXT format.

Similarly, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in SSMS will show the results of the query in GRID format.